# Authenticate with WhenIWork API using AlmamoFire (Swift)

Tags: swift, alamofire

#### UPDATED Question:

I got in touch with the WhenIWork Team and discovered that they need the username and password to be passed in the body but with our a form. So I have solved.  If you look at the answer below, it works.

Thanks everyone!

---

I am trying to get the access token from WhenIWork using Swift and Alamofire on Xcode, the json returned Success but says "Application Not Found Error"

I've been looking for documentation from WhenIWork Doc but without success on error code. (They don't have any error in the 1xxx range)

Ideas? I am new to Swift (and coding in general) so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

#### Below is the Terminal answer:

```
SUCCESS: {
    code = 1110;
    error = "Application not found";
}
[Request]: POST https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login/
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6080000325e0> { URL: https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login/ } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, W-Date-Format, Content-Type, Accept, W-Token, W-UserId, W-Key, branch";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 17 Aug 2017 17:11:08 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Database" = ro;
    "X-State" = "RequestId: 0f853dd4-836f-11e7-90f4-0242e14cb0c5, LoginId: 0, AccountId: 0";
    "X-Timer-Database" = "0.0052359104156494";
    "X-Timer-Total" = "0.012078046798706";
} }
```

#### Code:

```
func logInWhenIWork() {
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "username": "cxxxx@xxxx.ca",
         "password": "xxxxxxx",
          "W-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxsxx"
    ]

Alamofire.request("https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
    debugPrint(response)

    if let json = response.result.value { 
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }  else {
        print(response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `curl` example they [give](http://dev.wheniwork.com/#authentication)? Just to see if your authentication and their service is working properly.

Comment: Yes I have. and yes it's working properly. I think I found my problem. They want me to append the username and password as httpbody. But somehow I can't seem to get Alamofire to do a header call as well as a httpbody encoding.

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect the new information and focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who wanted the answer. I finally figured it out. Here it is

func logInWhenIWork() {

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["W-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxx","Content-Type":"application/json"]


    let parameters = ["username": "ss@xxx.ca", "password": "sssdsds"]

    do {
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    } catch {
        // No-op
    }

    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
```

//                print("JSON: (json)")

```
            let token = json["token"].stringValue

           let newUserID = json["users"][0]["id"].int
            print(newUserID)

            self.wUserID = String(describing: newUserID)
```

//                print(token)

```
            self.wToken = token

            if self.wToken != "" {

                print("Successfully logged in")

            } else {
                print("Log In Failed")
            }





        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }



    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Alamofire much but I tried the following:

```
let parameters = ["username":"user@example.com",
                  "password": "*******"]
let headers = ["W-Key": "iworksoharditsnotfunny"]
var req = Alamofire.request("https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login",
                            parameters: parameters,
                            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                            headers: headers)
```

The request ends up looking like this:

```
curl -v \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
    -H "User-Agent: Unknown/Unknown (Unknown; build:Unknown; OS X 10.12.6) Alamofire/1.0" \
    -H "W-Key: iworksoharditsnotfunny" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
    -d "{\"username\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"*******\"}" \
    "https://api.wheniwork.com/2/login"
```

Which seems to pretty much match the [example given](http://dev.wheniwork.com/#authentication) in the WhenIWork API documentation. I don't have an account so I can't test it directly.

Comment: Thanks! I got in touch and found out why. And thanks for the suggestion of updating the question. Brand new here so making all the newbie mistakes.

Comment: I believe my answer does roughly the same as what you posted in a more direct way. Did you give it a try with your values filled-in? Also, their example uses a GET and your answer uses a POST.